# What is the flaw in my thinking for the graph of this function?

Tags: differential-geometry, graphing-functions

Consider the map

$$ f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, (x,y) \mapsto x^3 + y^3 + xy$$

This defines a surface in $\mathbb R^3$. Let's consider some level set $f(x,y) = c$:

[image]

(see [here](https://books.google.co.jp/books/about/Curves_and_Singularities.html?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&redir_esc=y) page 67)

I think of these pictures as viewed from above looking down on the x-y-plane. Using these 3 pictures to imagine what the surface should look like lead me to believe that the surface should look like this:

(apologies, this is the best I could do with the online drawing tool)

[image]

To verify this I then used an [online plotter](http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/) which yielded this:

[image]

Now my question is:

> How is it possible that the level lines of the last graph yield the
>   level lines in the first three pictures? I do not see how this is
>   possible.

(the range of the plot I used was $-1 \le x,y \le 1$ and $-1.3 \le z \le 3$, varying the range does not seem to change the graph)

Comment: I curves in the last picture are intersections of the surface with planes $\{x = x_0\}$ and $\{y = y_0\}$, or if you like, the coordinate curves of the graph parameterization of the surface. In particular, they are not level curves.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your sketch doesn't even look like the graph of a smooth function - remember that it should just be a deformed plane with nowhere vertical tangents. Here's an animation I whipped up that might help your intuition for this example:

[image: level curves animation]

In general it's helpful to remember how changes in the topology of the level curves correspond to local features of the function: a loop appearing/disappearing corresponds to a local extremum, while a transition across a self-intersection like you see in this example at $c=0$ corresponds to a saddle point.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me! I didn't see the bump on the graph that I plotted.

Comment: This animation is excellent, how did you make it?

Comment: @mt_: Mathematica. Here's the code for an interactive version: http://pastebin.com/9GjqGBAp

Comment: @astudent High values of x and y hide the bump in the scale. If you plot it to xmax = ymax = 0.5, it is clearly visible.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: That's awesome. Is there a built-in way to make a GIF or video out of it, or did you use external software?

Comment: @Davidmh Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Mehrdad http://pastebin.com/yZTKdZaf

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: Oh wow, thanks!!